# Infinispan - synchronization between node in a cluster

Tags: caching, infinispan

have you any idea of when we add a new node in a existant cluster in infinispan ,  how many times the synchronizations between nodes will take ? and if try to call a service in my cache before the synchronization are terminated , i will have an error ?

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Synchronization, or state transfer, is non-blocking, so you can continue executing operations while that happens.

Comment: okey, and if i want to block all my treament when the Synchronization deesnt terminated ? how can i do that ?

Comment: hello Galder , please i have a question , I want to know the way how I can detect the cache rebalance is finished in infinispan ? when we have a cluster composed of nodes in a replication mode.

Comment: [Context=org.infinispan.CONFIG] ISPN100010: Finished rebalance with members [CSPYCHAKIR-29032, CSPYCHAKIR-60692], topology id 7
[Context=local] ISPN100002: Starting rebalance with members [CSPYCHAKIR-29032, CSPYCHAKIR-60692], phase READ_OLD_WRITE_ALL, topology id 3
[Context=local] ISPN100009: Advancing to rebalance phase READ_ALL_WRITE_ALL, topology id 4
[Context=local] ISPN100009: Advancing to rebalance phase READ_NEW_WRITE_ALL, topology id 5
[Context=local] ISPN100010: Finished rebalance with members [CSPYCHAKIR-29032, CSPYCHAKIR-60692], topology id 6

Comment: how can i detect that rebalance is finished please ?

Comment: there is listener which can notify me ?

Comment: @user3822342 you have opened a lot of questions on similar topics. If you want an interactive conversation you should really talk to the Infinispan team in the chat (you can find a link to that under the community / ask for help on the Infinispan webpage).

Comment: Check our state transfer JMX component to get information about rebalance status: http://docs.jboss.org/infinispan/9.4/apidocs/jmxComponents.html#StateTransferManager